# How do you add syntax highlighting for Less in Notepad++?

Tags: css, notepad++, highlight, less

I want Notepad++ to treat my *.less* files just as my *.css* files and thereby get syntax highlighting for any `.less` files I open.

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for Super User, especially considering a similar question already exists there.

Comment: First time i heard someone mention Super User but I'm guessing you're right. Is that forum more application oriented?

Comment: yes, it's application oriented. However, this question is partly programmer related. It can go to either site.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To get LESS syntax highlighting, you have to download and import a *user defined language* file. Here are some links to language files:

- [LESS language file](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/less.xml), as listed in the [Notepad++ User Defined Language List](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files)
- [LESS language file on GitHub](https://github.com/azrafe7/LESS-for-Notepad-plusplus)

Installation instructions from the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/azrafe7/LESS-for-Notepad-plusplus):

> - Download the `less.xml` file
> - Open Notepad++
> - Go to `Language -> Define your language...`, click on `Import...` and select the `less.xml` file you've downloaded
> - Close and restart Notepad++
> - Done

Another way to install language files is to [copy them into a file in the Notepad++ installation directory](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files#How_to_install_user_defined_language_files).

Comment: This answer addresses much more the original question than the one of alex. Thank you.

Comment: Not a huge savings in time, but you don't have to download the file. You can just paste the URL as if it were a file, when you get to the Import dialog.

Answer (score 4):

Download from [this page](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files) the XML file of the language to add (such as [Less](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/commun/userDefinedLang/less.xml))

In Notepad++ open `Language` menu > `Define your language...` and `Import` the file